# Bower behind a firewall in VS 2015

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Inside visual studio 2015 bower is unable to download the dependencies due to the some firewall restrictions. Outside of VS I know you can tell bower to use http instead of git and I have that set and it works. But inside VS it still will not download the dependencies. Getting exit code "#-532462766". Thanks for any help you can give.